# How can I enable magic mouse momentum scrolling in Windows 7?

Tags: bootcamp, windows, mouse

I have my magic mouse and I've gotten it working with windows 7. Left and right click work as well as scrolling.

Now I want smooth/inertial scrolling as well as middle click. Is it possible?

Also is there a way to imitate the ability in OS X to scroll any window regardless of whether or not that window has focus?

Comment: You could break out the part about scrolling in windows which are not in focus to a separate question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answering the second part of the question, [KatMouse](http://ehiti.de/katmouse/) is your solution.  It brings very Mac-like cursor/scroll interaction to Windows.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe there is any way to setup middle click unless you do something like map a key/mouse combination to middle click in some applications.  The fact that the magic mouse doesn't have a middle button means you can never 'tell' window that you've pressed it.  If someone wrote a driver which accepted both right & left buttons being clicked as a middle click that might be possible but I don't know of anything which exists which does that.